# Como faço para escrever dados de um ArrayList para um arquivo txt (Além de fazer a Leitura do arquivo ao iniciar o programa)?

Tags: java, array, arquivo, estrutura-de-dados, arraylist

[Repositório Github do Projeto Completo](https://github.com/matigous/RhJob)

/*Uma empresa de recursos humanos, especializada em recolocações no mercado(vagas de emprego), 
solicita a criação de um sistema para informatizar suas ações.Assim, 
ela deseja cadastrar os candidatos com seu nome (String) e idade (int). 
Oscandidatos podem ser desempregados, que tem o tempo em meses (int) que nãotrabalha ou empregados, que tem o nome da empresa (String),
onde está atualmente.As vagas tem a descrição (String) e o salário oferecido (double). As vagas podem serde estágio, 
que em o tempo em meses (int) ou contrato, que pode ser temporário ounão   (boolean).   
Criar   um   programa   em   Java   para   cadastrar   os   candidatos desempregados   ou   empregados)   e   cadastrar   
as   vagas   (estágio   ou   contrato).   Osistema  deve ser capaz de cadastrar os candidatos para as vagas. 
Criar uma classe para criar a empresa de RH (main). Nesta classe deverá haver ummenu para cadastrar candidatos, cadastrar 
vagas, cadastrar candidato x vaga, listarvagas por tipo, mostrar quantidade de candidatos e sua situação e os candidatos x vaga.
Autor: Matheus Vilela Diniz Maia 
Main EmpresaRH
*/

https://github.com/matigous/RhJob

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EmpresaRH {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner readNum = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner readStr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ok = "";
        ArrayList<CandidatoEmpregado> candidatoEmpregado = new ArrayList<CandidatoEmpregado>();
        ArrayList<CandidatoDesempregado> candidatoDesempregado = new ArrayList<CandidatoDesempregado>();
        ArrayList<VagaEstagio> vagaEstagio = new ArrayList<VagaEstagio>();
        ArrayList<VagaContrato> vagaContrato = new ArrayList<VagaContrato>();
        ArrayList<CandidatoEmpregado_VagaEstagio> candidatoEmpregado_vagaEstagio_Obj = new ArrayList<CandidatoEmpregado_VagaEstagio>();
        ArrayList<CandidatoEmpregado_VagaContrato> candidatoEmpregado_vagaContrato_Obj = new ArrayList<CandidatoEmpregado_VagaContrato>();
        ArrayList<CandidatoDesempregado_VagaEstagio> candidatoDesempregado_vagaEstagio_Obj = new ArrayList<CandidatoDesempregado_VagaEstagio>();
        ArrayList<CandidatoDesempregado_VagaContrato> candidatoDesempregado_vagaContrato_Obj = new ArrayList<CandidatoDesempregado_VagaContrato>();

        do {
            System.out.printf(
                    "\nCadastrar Candidato (1) / Cadastrar Vaga (2) / Cadastrar Candidato x Vaga (3) / Listar Vagas p/ Tipo (4) / Qt de Cadidatos e Situacao (5) / Cadidato p/ Vaga (6): ");
            switch (readNum.nextInt()) {
            case 1: /* cadastrar candidatos */
                System.out.printf("\nEmpregado (1) / Desempregado (2): ");
                int estado = readNum.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("Nome Candidato: ");
                String nome = readStr.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("Idade Candidato: ");
                int idade = readNum.nextInt();
                if (estado == 1) {
                    System.out.printf("Empresa Atual: ");
                    String empresaAtual = readStr.nextLine();
                    candidatoEmpregado.add(new CandidatoEmpregado(nome, idade, empresaAtual));
                } else if (estado == 2) {
                    System.out.printf("Tempo desempregado: ");
                    int mesesSemTrabalho = readNum.nextInt();
                    candidatoDesempregado.add(new CandidatoDesempregado(nome, idade, mesesSemTrabalho));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Escolha Invalida! ");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 2: /* cadastrar vagas */
                System.out.printf("\nVaga Estagio (1) / Vaga Contrato (2): ");
                int estado2 = readNum.nextInt();
                System.out.printf("Descricao da Vaga: ");
                String descricao = readStr.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("Salario da Vaga: ");
                double salario = readNum.nextDouble();
                if (estado2 == 1) {
                    System.out.printf("Duracao (meses): ");
                    int tempoMes = readNum.nextInt();
                    vagaEstagio.add(new VagaEstagio(descricao, salario, tempoMes));
                } else if (estado2 == 2) {
                    System.out.printf("Eh temporaria (Sim > (1)) (Nao > (0)): ");
                    boolean ehTemporario = (readNum.nextInt() == 1) ? true : false;
                    vagaContrato.add(new VagaContrato(descricao, salario, ehTemporario));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Escolha Invalida! ");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 3: /* cadastrar candidato x vaga */
                System.out.printf("\nCadastrar Cand. Empregado (1) ou Desempregado (2) p/ a Vaga: ");
                int escolha1 = readNum.nextInt();
                // Empregado
                if (escolha1 == 1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatoEmpregado.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf("(Cadiadato Empregado (" + (i + 1) + ") nome: "
                                + candidatoEmpregado.get(i).getNome() + ") ");
                    }
                    System.out.printf("\nEscolha o n do Candidato: ");
                    int numeroCandidatoEmpregado = readNum.nextInt();
                    System.out.printf("Cadastrar p/ Estagio (1) ou Contrato (2): ");
                    int escolha2 = readNum.nextInt();
                    /* Estagio */
                    if (escolha2 == 1) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < vagaEstagio.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.printf("(Vaga Estagio (" + (i + 1) + ") nome: "
                                    + vagaEstagio.get(i).getDescricao() + ") ");
                        }
                        System.out.printf("\nEscolha o n da Vaga: ");
                        int numeroVagaEstagio = readNum.nextInt();
                        candidatoEmpregado_vagaEstagio_Obj.add(
                                new CandidatoEmpregado_VagaEstagio(candidatoEmpregado.get(numeroCandidatoEmpregado - 1),
                                        vagaEstagio.get(numeroVagaEstagio - 1)));
                    } /* Contrato */ else if (escolha2 == 2) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < vagaContrato.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.printf("(Vaga Contrato (" + (i + 1) + ") nome: "
                                    + vagaContrato.get(i).getDescricao() + ") ");
                        }
                        System.out.printf("\nEscolha o n da Vaga: ");
                        int numeroVagaContrato = readNum.nextInt();
                        candidatoEmpregado_vagaContrato_Obj.add(new CandidatoEmpregado_VagaContrato(
                                candidatoEmpregado.get(numeroCandidatoEmpregado - 1),
                                vagaContrato.get(numeroVagaContrato - 1)));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Escolha Invalida! ");
                        break;
                    }
                    // Desempregado
                } else if (escolha1 == 2) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatoDesempregado.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf("(Cadiadato Desempregado (" + (i + 1) + ") nome: "
                                + candidatoDesempregado.get(i).getNome() + ") ");
                    }
                    System.out.printf("\nEscolha o n do Candidato: ");
                    int numeroCandidatoDesempregado = readNum.nextInt();
                    System.out.printf("Cadastrar p/ Estagio (1) ou Contrato (2): ");
                    int escolha3 = readNum.nextInt();
                    /* Estagio */
                    if (escolha3 == 1) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < vagaEstagio.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.printf("(Vaga Estagio (" + (i + 1) + ") nome: "
                                    + vagaEstagio.get(i).getDescricao() + ") ");
                        }
                        System.out.printf("\nEscolha o n da Vaga: ");
                        int numeroVagaEstagio = readNum.nextInt();
                        candidatoDesempregado_vagaEstagio_Obj.add(new CandidatoDesempregado_VagaEstagio(
                                candidatoDesempregado.get(numeroCandidatoDesempregado - 1),
                                vagaEstagio.get(numeroVagaEstagio - 1)));
                    } /* Contrato */ else if (escolha3 == 2) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < vagaContrato.size(); i++) {
                            System.out.printf("(Vaga Contrato (" + (i + 1) + ") nome: "
                                    + vagaContrato.get(i).getDescricao() + ") ");
                        }
                        System.out.printf("\nEscolha o n da Vaga: ");
                        int numeroVagaContrato = readNum.nextInt();
                        candidatoDesempregado_vagaContrato_Obj.add(new CandidatoDesempregado_VagaContrato(
                                candidatoDesempregado.get(numeroCandidatoDesempregado - 1),
                                vagaContrato.get(numeroVagaContrato - 1)));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Escolha Invalida! ");
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Escolha Invalida! ");
                    break;
                }

                break;
            case 4: /* listar vagas por tipo */
                System.out.print("\nVaga Estagio (1) / Vaga Contrato (2): ");
                int escolha4 = readNum.nextInt();
                if (escolha4 == 1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < vagaEstagio.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf(
                                "(Vaga Estagio (" + (i + 1) + ") nome: " + vagaEstagio.get(i).getDescricao() + ") \n");
                    }
                } else if (escolha4 == 2) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < vagaContrato.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf(
                                "(Vaga Contrato (" + (i + 1) + ") nome: " + vagaContrato.get(i).getDescricao() + ") ");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Escolha Invalida! ");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 5: /* mostrar quantidade de candidatos e sua situação */
                for (int i = 0; i < candidatoEmpregado.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("\n(Cadiadato Empregado " + (i + 1) + " > nome: "
                            + candidatoEmpregado.get(i).getNome() + ") ");
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < candidatoDesempregado.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("\n(Cadiadato Desempregado " + (i + 1) + " > nome: "
                            + candidatoDesempregado.get(i).getNome() + ") ");
                }
                break;
            case 6: /* Candidato por Vaga */
                if (candidatoEmpregado_vagaEstagio_Obj.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatoEmpregado_vagaEstagio_Obj.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf("\n"+candidatoEmpregado_vagaEstagio_Obj.get(i));
                    }
                }
                if (candidatoDesempregado_vagaEstagio_Obj.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatoDesempregado_vagaEstagio_Obj.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf("\n"+candidatoDesempregado_vagaEstagio_Obj.get(i));
                    }
                }
                if (candidatoEmpregado_vagaContrato_Obj.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatoEmpregado_vagaContrato_Obj.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf("\n"+candidatoEmpregado_vagaContrato_Obj.get(i));
                    }
                }
                if (candidatoDesempregado_vagaContrato_Obj.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatoDesempregado_vagaContrato_Obj.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.printf("\n"+candidatoDesempregado_vagaContrato_Obj.get(i));
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("Continuar (Y/N): ");
            ok = readStr.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        } while (ok.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));


    }

}
```

Comment: Qual é o objetivo de escrever os dados num ficheiro e os ler de um ficheiro?
Se quer ter persistência de dados o melhor seria usar um banco de dados.

Comment: Eu concordo que usar BD é melhor, mas meu professor quer persistência num arquivo de texto.

Comment: Nesse caso tem de definir como vai guardar as informações no ficheiro.
Se cada linha do ficheiro é um indíce da ArrayList e cada elemento se separa por virgula ou outro separador que desejar.
Depois para ler do ficheiro e popular a ArrayList tem de usar o processo contrário.

Answer (score 1):

A sua melhor opção nesse cenário é usar o padrão de projeto DAO - Data Access Object. Esse padrão de projeto permite que
você crie uma camada de abstração entre a sua aplicação e a fonte de dados. Dessa forma você pode trocar essa fonte de dados
no futuro sem impactar as outras camadas do seu código. Você vai precisar de poucas classes para implementar esse comportamento. Uma combinação 
com o padrão Factory (permite criar objetos ocultando detalhes da implementação) será perfeita para o seu projeto.

Segue exemplo completo para a classe Vaga:

A interface DAO será usada para criar uma hierarquia de classes que irão implementar o padrão de projetos DAO.

```
//DAO.java
package rhjob.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public interface DAO<T extends Serializable> {

    void persist(List<T> list);
    List<T> findAll();

}
```

A interface VagaDAO será a superclasse de todas as implementações de DAO para guardar as vagas, independentemente o banco de dados.

```
//VagaDAO.java
package rhjob.dao;

import rhjob.Vaga;

public interface VagaDAO extends DAO<Vaga> {}
```

A classe VagaDaoImpl será a implementação padrão da interface VagaDAO. É nela que a lógica para ler/gravar dados em arquivo vai acontecer.
Na implementação desse exemplo iremos armazenar os dados em um arquivo de texto que é informado no construtor do DAO. Os dados serão guardados como JSON. Iremos usar a biblioteca Gson, do Google.

```
//VagaDaoImpl.java
package rhjob.dao.impl;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import rhjob.Vaga;
import rhjob.dao.VagaDAO;

public class VagaDAOImpl implements VagaDAO {

    private final File file;

    public VagaDAOImpl(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(List<Vaga> list) {
        try {
            storeAsJson(list);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VagaDAOImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Vaga> findAll() {
        try {
            return readAll();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VagaDAOImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    private void storeAsJson(List<Vaga> list) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(list);

        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file)) {
            out.println(jsonString);
        }
    }

    private List<Vaga> readAll() throws IOException {
        final String textData = readTextData();
        return new Gson().fromJson(textData, new TypeToken<List<Vaga>>(){}.getType());
    }

    private String readTextData() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(sc.nextLine()).append("\n");
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}

//DAOFactory.java
package rhjob.dao;

import java.io.File;
import rhjob.dao.impl.VagaDAOImpl;

public class DAOFactory {

    private static final File vagasFile;

    static {
        vagasFile = new File("D:\\vagas.json");
    }

    public static VagaDAO createVagaDAO() {
        return new VagaDAOImpl(vagasFile);
    }
}

//Vaga.java
package rhjob;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Vaga implements Serializable {

    private String descricao;
    private double salario;

    public Vaga() {
    }

    public Vaga(String descricao, double salario) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public double getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }

    public void setSalario(double salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 17 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.descricao);
        hash = 17 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.salario) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.salario) >>> 32));
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Vaga other = (Vaga) obj;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.salario) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.salario)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.descricao, other.descricao)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vaga{" + "descricao=" + descricao + ", salario=" + salario + '}';
    }        
}


//Main.java
package rhjob;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import rhjob.dao.DAOFactory;
import rhjob.dao.VagaDAO;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Vaga> vagas = new ArrayList<>();
        vagas.add(new Vaga("VAGA 1", 1000));
        vagas.add(new Vaga("VAGA 2", 6000));
        vagas.add(new Vaga("VAGA 3", 1000));
        vagas.add(new Vaga("VAGA 4", 4000));
        vagas.add(new Vaga("VAGA 5", 1000));
        vagas.add(new Vaga("VAGA 6", 2000));
        vagas.add(new Vaga("VAGA 7", 3500));


        VagaDAO dao = DAOFactory.createVagaDAO();        
        dao.persist(vagas);

        System.out.println(dao.findAll());
    }   
}
```